# curl com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, libcurl

estou tentando fazer uma solicitação para uma pagina assim como faço quando usso o curl no php porem quero via jquery porem ele ta q n tenho permição, queria saber como resolvo isso.

meu codigo ate o momento:

```
  <script>
        function regex_correct() {
            $.ajax({
                 url: "https://homebeta1.000webhostapp.com/ts/regex/1.php?regex="+document.getElementById('original').value,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    //process the JSON data etc
                }
            })

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: tem algum erro na consola?

Comment: vala q eu n tenho autorisaçã do site